# how to define to use existing database server in ARM template?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

Tuning the quick start, helps me deploy the App and DB. The thing I noticed was each time, my ARM template dictate to create a new DB server and load database. The tricky thing is that subscription got a limit of 6 DB servers.

Is there a way, I could define this as a configuration parameter and ARM template uses this db server than creating new one?

```
Error Message I get in shell console is :
>New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers 
>'sqlserverXXXXXt6fXX' failed with message 'Cannot move or create server. 
>Subscription '123XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXe5X' will exceed server quota.'
```

Any suggestion or pointers would be great help!

Thanks

H Bala

Comment: Can you share your deployment template?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I just figured out a way and I have posted it below. It would be great to know your view or any alternative! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My bad! This could be done with setting the servername variable to existing database server name and letting it be fixed always.

```
"resources": [
{
  "name": "[variables('sqlserverName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "SqlServer"
```

to

```
"resources": [
    {
     "name": "{**sqldbservername_desired**}",
     "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "tags": {
       "displayName": "SqlServer"
```

Thanks & Regards,

H Bala